# Is there any clean source code for Microsoft.SharePoint.dll 2013 on the internet?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

for **learning purposes**, I want to debug code inside `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`, I reflect the code and save it as project (using reflector) but when I try to build this project I find a lot of bugs, Is there any clean source code for `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` 2013 on the internet?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to debug?

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.dll it self, as example: viewlsts.aspx page code behind

Comment: Not possible to debug inside proprietary source code. What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Why it is not possible, at the end it is DLL, I can reflect and replace it on my development server, then debug it. but using reflector need a lot of time to clean it and make it build-able, because that I'm asking if there is already someone made this before

Comment: No one can do this except Microsoft. Assume you create a private project which you distributed to clients. And client trying to debug your dll? Its not possible.

Comment: forget business, I'm talking technicality and for learning purposes. I'll not sell anything. and as I know there is no technical issues to reflect the code and build it again then replace and debug it. and I did this before for another products. what I'm asking, if there is anyone do it before, this will save my time to reflect and fix. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea. You can't just simply take source code and create a dll out of that. There should be dependencies and on top of that these dll's will be signed with a KEY. Which only Microsoft Has.

You can use Reflector and read the code and understand what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: "very bad idea"?! any way this is for learning purposes and it will make you understand the product that you working with better than anything else

Comment: what is the dependencies? is it another DLLs?

Comment: what about changing DLL PublicKeyToken every where?  are you still 100% sure this is not going work.

Comment: is still a bad idea?

Comment: then let's inform .net reflector team that the build tools (such as VS .net reflector) to serve bad ideas :) I'm trust you will start using this bad idea soon ;) now you are sure it is not woke 1%

Comment: I don't know why you delete your all comments, it was useful. did you start using this debugging technique?

Comment: I deleted the comments because my point is clearly stated in my answer. I have never been into a situation to debug MS dlls in my entire experience.

Answer (score 1):

I did it (using .net reflector for visual studio 2013), and now I can debug the core SharePoint dlls easily.

but the issue is, this is a trial version, I'm still need clean source code :( , I'll try to figure out how reflector do it and do the same.

[image]

**Note:** I think it is worth to write articles about this.

Comment: This is just an add in to visual studio which basically get the dll from GAC and allows to step through the code. It's not like REFLECTOR team has rebuilt the dll as you were trying to do.

Comment: yes, this is what I'm asked in my question :), I need to debug, not rebuild